# How to deal with missing values in Kruskal-Wallis test in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, statistics, kruskal-wallis

The Matlab documentation seems unclear about how to ignore missing data when using [`kruskalwallis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kruskalwallis.html), the Kruskal-Wallis (or any other related) test. The same goes for unequal group size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very late answer, but I ran into the same problem myself today, might as well help some future searcher.

The solution is pretty straightforward. kruskalwallis is primarily used on matrices and by default compares equal-sized columns, but it does allow you to instead assign groups manually, with the optional variable "group". I was attempting to check whether a single value was unlikely to belong to a distribution from a different set, so this was straightforward. I just added the value I wanted to test on to the end of the set I was testing against, then made "group" a vector of ones the same size as the set, with a "2" added to the end for the new value. Looks like it worked quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

For numeric data, the the standard missing data value in Matlab is [`NaN`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html). See [`ismissing`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismissing.html). See also [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/find-missing-data.html) from The MathWorks. For [tables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html), you might find [`standardizeMissing`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/standardizemissing.html) helpful as well as [`replaceWithMissing`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.replacewithmissing.html) for [dataset](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset-class.html) objects. I can't say anything about group size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I am aware of these functions. Instead I'm interested in statistical tests on data with missing values.

Comment: @user3503398: You asked "how to ignore missing data." You use `Nan`, as my answer indicates (almost all functions in the Statistics Toolbox use this convention). The rest of my answer is simply references and additional information.